# Redirect to Spring Data REST controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I use Spring Data REST in a Spring Boot application and I want to redirect a custom route to an entity controller generated one. Here is my code :

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class CustomUserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH, value = "/users/{id}/name/{newName}")
    public ModelAndView enable(@PathVariable Long id,
                               @PathVariable String newName) {
        User patchedUser = new User();
        patchedUser.setName(newName);

        // This is not working but I want to make a PATCH with my fragment of the user as the body
        return new ModelAndView("/users/" + id, "message", patchedUser);
    }
}
```

In fact, I just want to rewrite the PATCH route for the entity user, but for one specific field. Since it is well handled by the generated controller I thought I would be able to make a simple forwarding but I am not able to found the proper way to do it.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you ever tried `RedirectView` or just return a string which indicate the redirect url?

Comment: I tried this and it seems that the right controller is called then, but I still can't find the way to set my patchedUser in the body. So I'm still getting a 400 response with the message "No content to map...".

Comment: Thus my question can now be rewritten as : how can I programmatically add a request body before redirecting the request ?

Comment: If it always the redirected url responsible for service, you could store data in session. I guess current controller and redirected url both can access these data later.

Comment: in fact the redirect url is handled by spring data rest, so the only way to pass my data is to give a request body with the right json serialized data

Comment: Till now, I've no good solution. And I'm going to do some more research about this and post anything if I achieved.